# Visual Studio 2015 npm package.json devDependencies @types doesn't update?

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio-2015, npm

Using npm 4.5.0, TS 2.2, Angular v4 in Visual Studio 2015 (VS2015).

I have a package.json like this:

```javascript
{
 "name": "MyApp",
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "scripts": {
      "start": "npm prune --production=false"
  },
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "4.x",
    "@angular/common": "4.x",
    ...
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    ...
},
  "devDependencies": {
      "@types/core-js": "^0.9.35",
      "@types/jasmine": "2.5.x",
       ...
```

3 main questions I have:

1. When I try to Restore Packages the latest @types/core-js is not installed (stays  0.9.35, I expect 0.9.41 currently ), angular updated correctly...why does this not work?
2. Intellisense works fine hovering over things in dependencies like core-js, it shows the latest version info, but @angular and @types show unavailable, why?
3. I would like npm to show verbose output, I tried to put -dd in Tools->Options->Web->Package Installer for the npm arguments, but this didn't seem to work, can I get npm to show verbose output in VS2015? (I know this is Mads Kristensen's extension, but is there a way to get VS to cause npm to display verbose when it runs?)